# C# datatable column deletion issue

Tags: c#, datatable

I had an issue with a Data table contained inside another Data table I was passing into a method.

Basically I wanted to delete some columns and write the amended table to a file.

I then had other actions I wanted to do with the original DataTable. However I noticed that when I deleted the columns all the instances of that table including in the main had been deleted.

I was able to create a solution where I created a new table and filled it with data from the original.

But I was just looking for some insights into why this happens, shouldn't the original data be protected?

Also first time posting so sorry if something is weird with my post

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        //create tables
        DataTable OriginalTbl = CreateTbl();
        //pull the nested table out 
        DataTable NestedTbl = new DataTable();
        NestedTbl = (DataTable)(OriginalTbl.Rows[0]["Nested"]);
        //call the method
        RemoveCols(OriginalTbl);

        //try retrieving the data again 
        string Data;
        string Excps;
        //will throw error here 
        Data = NestedTbl.Rows[0]["Data"].ToString();
        Excps = NestedTbl.Rows[0]["Exceptions"].ToString();
        // something else 

    }
    static DataTable CreateTbl()
    {
        DataTable OriginalTbl = new DataTable();
        DataTable NestedTbl = new DataTable();
        OriginalTbl.Columns.Add("Nested", typeof(DataTable));

        NestedTbl.Columns.Add("Data");
        NestedTbl.Columns.Add("Exceptions");
        NestedTbl.Columns.Add("results");

        DataRow NestedRow = NestedTbl.NewRow();
        NestedRow["Data"] = "blah data";
        NestedRow["Exceptions"] = "blah Exceptions";
        NestedRow["results"] = "blah Results";
        NestedTbl.Rows.Add(NestedRow);

        // add to the original table
        DataRow OrigRow = OriginalTbl.NewRow();
        OrigRow["Nested"] = NestedTbl;
        OriginalTbl.Rows.Add(OrigRow);
        return OriginalTbl;
    }

    static void RemoveCols(DataTable MainTbl)
    {
        DataTable NestedTbl = (DataTable)(MainTbl.Rows[0]["Nested"]);
        NestedTbl.Columns.Remove("Data");
        NestedTbl.Columns.Remove("Exceptions");
        //blah do something here 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I noticed that when I deleted the columns **all the instances** of that table including in the main had been deleted.

Not exactly, you only have one *instance* of the nested `DataTable` but you have multiple *references* to that instance.  No matter which reference to the nested table you use, the instance itself is what gets modified when you add or remove columns, or otherwise change data.

This is one of the basics of OO programming you'll definitely need to get your head around.

```
// Creates a new instance of DataTable
DataTable NestedTbl = new DataTable();

// Immediately throw away the new instance for the existing instance stored in OriginalTbl
NestedTbl = (DataTable)(OriginalTbl.Rows[0]["Nested"]);
```

When you do this, you're not creating a copy of the original nested table.  You're simply overwriting the reference to the new instance with one to the existing nested table.

Comment: thanks that helped with further reading , i understand the issue now

Comment: @cliomhsolas That's great, I'm glad it helped!  Would you kindly accept my answer if you feel that it answered your question?